# rename many text file using a specific line in the files

Tags: matlab, batch-file, rename

I want to rename many text files using the content of its first line.
e.g      `filename=data1.txt`

```
firstline=AAA 123BC DD



new filename=123BC.txt
```

Any idea using batch file or matlab?
Thank you for your help
P.s this is not a code

Comment: So do you mean rename data1.txt with characters between two separated characters? e.g. bb 1234 cccc  <- Will this works?

Comment: I don't understand what it is you want.

Comment: Not clear what your text files are. But use fgets to read the first line and then change the file name using the dos command (dos(['rename "' oldname '" "' newname '"'])

Comment: You can use [`movefile`](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/movefile.html) to do the renaming part directly from Matlab. For finding the right file name from the first line, you need to give more details about how your files are structured.

Answer (score 1):

If you need the second word of the first line you can use,

```
files = dir('*.txt');
for i = 1:numel(files)
   fname = files(i).name;
   fid = fopen(fname);
   c = textscan(fid, '%s','delimiter','\n');
   firstline = strsplit(c{1}{1},' ');
   if numel(firstline)>=2
       secondword = firstline{2};
       copyfile(fname,sprintf('%s.txt',secondword));
   end
   fclose(fid);
end
```

Comment: sorry if i wasn't clear...Ineed to take the second word of the first line.i will modify the code you posted but I think this should work.I will try and post the results. Thank you very much

Comment: the second word has a comma in the end (e.g AAA,) so it renames the files as AAA,.txt. Btw it works very good. I will try to exclude the comma from the second word. Thank you very much for your help

Comment: Problem solved modifying the delimiter of strplit funcion in ', ' instead of ' ' . Thank you !!